# Import python module from subfolder, where the module contains uninitialized parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, directory

Could I ask how to correctly handle the contents of this subdirectory module in order to import it into foo.py?

---

There is a python script named "foo.py" held in "folder1".

```
\folder1
foo.py
    \folder2
    __init__.py
    bar.py
```

foo.py is running a bigquery API call, which requires a schema to be passed.
This schema is being held in the variable "module_variable", contained in bar.py, held in the folder2 subdirectory.
The init file is empty.

```
module_variable = [
            bigquery.SchemaField('a', 'STRING', mode='REQUIRED'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('b', 'STRING', mode='REQUIRED'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('c', 'STRING', mode='REQUIRED'),
        ]
```

When attempting to import "module_variable" into foo.py with this method:

```
from folder1.folder2.bar import module_variable
```

The following error is returned:

```
NameError: name 'bigquery' is not defined
```

Could I ask how to correctly handle or modify the contents of this module in order to pass the parameters into foo.py?

Comment: Can you please clarify? ``bigquery`` must be defined in ``bar.py``, *just like any other name you want to use*. What prevents you from having ``bigquery`` defined inside ``bar.py``?

Comment: Thank you, are you saying that bigquery would need to be initialized in BOTH foo.py and bar.py? (So duplicate "import bigquery" at the top of bar.py). I believed that because the execution was occurring on the foo.py side there wouldn't need to be a duplicate initialization.

Comment: Yes, you need to import a module in each module where you want to use it.